# Android Activity Transition Animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

What I am trying to achieve is : start a new activity with a transition animation for the exiting activity **only**.

I would like to slide up the current activity, where the new activity will be behind the current one.

Here is the slide up animation : **R.layout.slide_up**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

Here is how I am applying the activity animation transition :

```
overridePendingTransition ( 0 , R.anim.slide_up );
```

I am using 0 for the entering activity since I do not want any animation for the new activity, and it is not working (the animation is not performed). If I use an animation for entering activity too, it works (both animations are performed), like such :

```
overridePendingTransition ( R.anim.slide_out , R.anim.slide_up );
```

where **R.anim.slide_out** :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Any ideas ?

I am working on Android 4.1.2 and Android 4.0.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alter your exit animation so that it renders over top of the entering activity.

**R.anim.slide_up**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:zAdjustment="top">

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

Then you can do what you were originally doing to set the animation.

```
overridePendingTransition ( 0 , R.anim.slide_up );
```

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly the same transition and such animation works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="100%" android:zAdjustment="top"
android:duration="300" />
```

Comment: That's because it's not exactly the same transition.  You have the zAdjustment="top" property set which allows the exiting animation to play over top the entering animation since by default the entering animation plays over the exiting.

Answer (score 3):

Call the below method after startActivity method.

```
 overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

This will override the default  animation and do no animation. You can also give some custom animation if you like

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1,R.anim.animation2);

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are calling the intent to start the Activity, you need to modify the intent.
`ActivityOptions options = 
ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(AlbumListActivity.this);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());`

If you have any dedicated method to `setupTransitions()` You can put the next two lines of code there, Else you may put them in `onCreate()`

```
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT).setDuration(800));
```

**Gravity.RIGHT** is what determines the direction from which you want to start your next Activity. `setDuration()` method is optional, for smoother Transition I used it, You don't have to.

Explore more by playing around with different Gravity and setDuration Properties.