# android activity exit animation not work

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to show exit animation when start activity exit.

this is the slide ftom left to right anim file:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

below is where I use it to show exit animation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.fade_out_to_left);
```

but exitAnim does not work, my test device is Android 4.4, KitKat.

it was like if I specify whatever enter anim resource and it works fine, but if I specify no enter anim as 0 like the example above, then the exit anim does not work either

---

I found solution here that works for me [Android Activity Transition Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090451/android-activity-transition-animation)
set android:zAdjustment="top" will renders exit animation first

Comment: look this post [Activity Transition](http://blog.quent.in/index.php/2013/06/activity-transition-animations-like-the-vine-android-application/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing 0 to the method use `R.anim.slide_no_move`:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_no_move, R.anim.fade_out_to_left);
```

Comment: Explanation: 0 does not work, because enter and exit animation are played at the same time. If the new activity enters instantly (0) the exit animation can't be seen.

Answer (score 0):

slide no move as enter anim is not working after I tried it. 
this is my slide_no_move anim file, is there anything wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/animation_long_default_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
</set>
```